# Unity C# StartCoroutine() in Destroyed Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script in Unity with C# and the time of the Coroutine not working, second line with `forwardForce = 10f` has not been called
:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SlowPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float waitTime = 2f;

  private IEnumerator DecreaseSpeed ()
  {
     GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().forwardForce = 1f;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
     GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().forwardForce = 10f;
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter ()
  {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    StartCoroutine(DecreaseSpeed());
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you calling `OnTriggerEnter()` somewhere in the code? If you're trying to use the physics engine `Event` of the same name, you need to use `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {...}` instead of `void OnTriggerEnter() {...}`.

Also, what do you mean by "infinite"?

Comment: Is it possible that your `Time.timescale` is changed? This might affect `WaitForSeconds()`

Comment: Unrelated, but worth noting, `GameObject.Find()` is very slow and should be avoided if at all possible. Alternatives include `GameObject.FindObjectOfType(Type)` (unity recommends using a Singleton pattern instead) and `GameObject.FindWithTag(string)` (probably the best option whenever possible)

Answer (score 6):

You are destroying the GameObject hosting the coroutine, which will destroy the coroutine causing it not to finish. You will want to destroy the GameObject at the end of the coroutine, or use a static coroutine manager.

Comment: One could also put the Destroy() at the end of Coroutine, and before that moment just destroy MeshRendererer and Collider

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the cleanest way, but if really you want to destroy this game object it's not so easy:

```
private IEnumerator DecreaseSpeed ()
{
    GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().forwardForce = 1f;
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().forwardForce = 10f;
}
```

But better way is to inject calss to SlowPickup, that handle this coroutine

```
private TimeClass ts;

void Start ()
{
    ts = ...; //Inject
}

void OnTriggerEnter ()
{
    ts.RunCoroutine(); //Implement logic in TimeClass
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

It's should work.